# Asus ROG Strix B550-i AM4 RYZEN 5000

Tags: compatibility, motherboard

Will the motherboard Asus ROG Strix B550-i (AM4 slot using RYZEN 5000 CPU) work with Ubuntu 20.04? If it does, any issues I should be aware of?

Comment: You can always boot to a Live CD/DVD/USB to test out Ubuntu and see if it will work with your hardware.  Even if you use NVIDIA Graphics it should be fine but you might have to install graphics drivers separate to make it work since NVIDIA does not supply Open Source drivers.  They are easily installed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=strix+B550-i#list) this Asus ROG Strix B550-i motherboard works normally in various systems including latest LTS - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
See reports at [this link](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=board:asustek-rog-strix-b550-i-gaming-rev-x-0x).

All components are detected by Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and work normally. There are successful reports with both [AMD](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=50d0f206e1) and [Nvidia](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=55eb7f2e9b) video cards.
For successful AMD GPU operation you'll probably need HWE kernel.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered, much appreciated.